# Find item by arbitrary query

Tags: ruby, algorithm, parsing

Problem: I have item in database, wich called "AABGng-LS 4х4 0.66kV". AABG is vendor, ng-LS is type, 4*4 is cable cross-section, 0.66 kV is voltage. User must find this item for this queries:

- AABG ng LS 4х4 660 V
- AABGng-LS-660 4х4
- AABG ng-LS 0.66 4*4

How can it be solved (algorithm)? I prefer ruby language, but algorithm in any language can be suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem that you are describing is one of a search-index. this involves a lot of steps to get it working if you want to do it yourself, like normalizing, stemming, matching etc.

i would advise you to have a look at lucene based search indexes like elasticsearch, solr etc.